# How to find the max value when averaged over other objects and use a more concise code

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

**Question**

Print out the company's information that pays the highest average wage when calculating the company's average wage at the wages of employees who receive more than the company's average wage.

=
When calculating the average wage of a company with the wages of only employees who receive more than the average wage of the company, print the information of the company that pays the highest average wage.

so I tried

```
with avg_sal(salary) as
    (select avg(salary)
    from worker
    group by company_name)
select worker.company_name, trunc(avg(worker.salary),0) as sal_avgup
from worker, avg_sal
where worker.salary > avg_sal.salary
group by worker.company_name
order by sal_avgup desc
```

```
my output
company_name sal_avgup
Google       ...
Amazon       ...
Facebook     ...
```

**but In this result, only the highest value of sal_avgup is needed. only google**

I only have to represent the company that gives the highest salary, but the code I create shows all the companies for the condition, **is there a way to extract only the highest value?**

Also, is it possible to make the code simpler?

my version is oracle11g

Comment: Don't use commas in the `FROM` clause!  Use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Sample data might help. More I read, less I understand.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think I'm not used to it..

Comment: @Littlefoot I added it

Comment: OK; that's *input*. What do you expect as *output*?

Comment: @Beenz . . . You should get used to it.  It is more powerful and just about everyone agrees is more readable and less prone to error.

Comment: @Littlefoot I added it!

Comment: @GordonLinoff ok.. I haven't learned it because I haven't left it in class yet. I will try it.

Comment: @beenz . . . It is a sad, sad class in 2020 that is not teaching proper `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 2 levels of aggregation and `RANK()` window function:

```
with 
  avgcte as (
    select company_name, avg(salary) avgsalary
    from worker
    group by company_name
  ),
  cte as (
    select w.company_name, avg(w.salary) sal_avgup,
      rank() over (order by avg(w.salary) desc) rnk
    from worker w inner join avgcte a
    on a.company_name = w.company_name and a.avgsalary < w.salary  
    group by w.company_name
  )
select company_name, sal_avgup 
from cte
where rnk = 1
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e6c2945a3fe760fa4a6aea579a4ab582).